# Yii renderPartial?

Tags: yii

вопрос во многом похож на [Как организовать ajax обновление элемента с id="myElem" в Yii?](https://toster.ru/q/143507)
но есть специфика - у меня статичные страницы отображаются во фрейме.
как в render отдать путь до страницы (с другого сервера). конечно нужно аяксом чтобы дерево не перерисовывалось

По клику $this->renderPartial('application.views.site.pages.about',array('param'=>1),false);
получаю

```
<h1>About</h1>

<p>This is a "static" page. You may change the content of this page
by updating the file <code>D:\open\OpenServer\domains\localhost\proizvodstvo\protected\views\site\pages
\about.php</code>.</p>
```

в фаербаге. а страница не отрисовывается...

на данный момент имею
view

```
 echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    $text = 'Click me', 
    array('req'), 
    $ajaxOptions=array (
        'type'=>'POST',
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'update'=>'#content',         
        ), 
    $htmlOptions=array ()
    );
```

controler

```
public function actionReq() {      
               echo $content = $this->renderPartial('application.views.site.pages.about');

}
```

Comment: Уточните: как связаны между собой renderPartial (для рендера вьюшек без layout) и фреймы страниц с другого сервера?

Comment: <div class="span-10">
           <?php 
                        $this->renderPartial('application.views.site.pages.about',array('param'=>1),false); ?>
           </div>

Comment: кто-то забыл `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем все элементарно

во вьюшке

```
 echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
$text = 'Click me', 
array('req'), 
$ajaxOptions=array (
    'type'=>'POST',        
    'update'=>'#content',
    'data' => array( 'id' => '44'),
    ), 
$htmlOptions=array (       
)
);
```

в контролере

```
public function actionReq() {
 $content = $this->renderPartial('application.views.site.pages.frameset');  
}
```

frameset.php

```
 $page = $_POST['id']; 
  $page = Page::model()->findByPk($page)->link;    
    echo '
    <iframe id="ifr" src="' . $page . '" align="center">    
    </iframe>';
```